# How can I convert [1, 2] to ['1', '2'] in haskell?

Tags: list, dictionary, haskell

What I have tried:

```
fn l = map conv l

conv l = show l
```

Then `fn [1,2] == ["1","2"]`

But these is an array of strings. I want an array of chars.

So I know to convert a string to char, we can use the following:

`"1" !! 0 == '1'`. So using the same logic:

`conv l = (show l) !! 0`

but this time I get back `"12"`

I assume `map` is combining chars together to form a string, but I want it in `['1', '2']` format

Comment: `"12"` is exactly equivalent to the list `['1', '2']` though. The first is syntactic sugar for the second.

Comment: What do you want `[42,-1]` to be converted to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[1,2,3]`, `['1','2','3']` and `["1","2","3"]` are *lists*, not arrays. Haskell, like many functional languages, does lots of stuff with lists and basically just uses arrays as an optimisation.

This includes strings: in Haskell, strings (meaning, [`Prelude.String`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:String)) are just lists of characters. Therefore, as Robert Zigmond commented, **`['1','2']` and `"12"` are *the exact same thing***, just written with different syntax.

So, if GHCi shows you `"12"` as the result of the test, it means you've done it right<sup>†</sup>: you do get a list of characters. This would be more obvious if you had used type signatures, like you *always* should do:

```
fn :: [Int] -> [Char]
fn = map conv
 where conv l = show l !! 0
```

Note that this gives a compile-time type error with the incorrect version `conv l = show l` that you had at first.

If for some reason you actually need output in the form `['1','2']`, you can easily write yourself a suitable showing function:

```
import Data.List (intercalate)

showPlainList :: [Char] -> String
showPlainList l = "[" ++ intercalate "," (map show l) ++ "]"
```

```
GHCi> showPlainList $ fn [1,2]
"['1','2']"
```

---

<sup>†</sup>I should remark that, although your function does work correctly, it is quite flawed, namely it only works properly on lists of non-negative one-digit numbers. The `!!` operator is generally a code smell, and unsafe (it fails when you're accessing past the end, i.e. in this case for empty result of `show`.

I don't know why you want this function anyway, so I also won't suggest a better implementation. Likely this is just a learning example, so fair enough. Just keep in mind in the future: if you find yourself using `head` or `!!`, you're probably doing something unidiomatic and unsafe.